# How to find intersection angle between two rectangles with given parameters?

Tags: geometry, vectors

I drew the problem on the attached picture. Points $P_0$, $P_1$, $P_2$ are known, length of r is also known. I need to learn how to find degree of $\alpha$.

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utgJ3.jpg)

[image]

Comment: i can not find any picture

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry

Comment: and a Point $P_3$ the coordinates of the middlepoint of the second rectangle?

Comment: $P_3$ is unknown. Actual problem comes down to finding $P_3$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there are 2 possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The half-side length $r$ is largely irrelevant other than as a way to generate the rotated rectangle or check that your data are consistent.
[image]

Extend the line segment $\overline{P_0P_1}$ and find its intersection with the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{P_0P_2}$. You can then chase angles to find $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer yet. Just a starting point

---

Let $X(a, b)$ be the point where the angle $\alpha$ is at.

First, using $P_0$ and $P_1$ find the coordinates of $X$.

Using this, the equation of the circle with radius $r$ around $X$ is

$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$

You are interested in the tangent to the circle which passes through $P_2$. There are 2 possibilities for this. Once this is found, $\alpha$ is $\pi$ minus the angle between the tangent and $P_0P_1$.